Permissions required to add and remove servers from Azure maintenance configuration
We use maintenance configurations as part of our Azure update manager configuration. For Azure VM's is there any role other than granting contributor role permission to the azure subscription that will allow for servers to be added and removed from maintenance configurations?
For Arc enabled servers this is not an issue as contributor role can be assigned to the resource groups that these servers belong to but for Azure VM's, as they are not in resource groups this is not possible.
There is no issue with permission to the maintenance configurations, the issue is with the required permission on the Azure VM's.
We tried creating a custom permission using the details below but this still does not allow Azure VM's to be added or removed.
Script details:
$customRole = @{
    Name        = "Maintenance Config VM Updater"
    Description = "Role with permissions to update maintenance configurations and associate VMs with them."
    Actions     = @(
        "Microsoft.Maintenance/configurations/write",
        "Microsoft.Maintenance/configurations/read",
        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write",
        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read"
    )
    NotActions  = @()
    DataActions = @()
    NotDataActions = @()
    AssignableScopes = @(
        "/subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>"
    )
}

# Convert the properties to JSON
$customRoleJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $customRole -Depth 10
 
# Create the custom role in Azure
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile (New-TemporaryFile -Value $customRoleJson)


To add or remove VMs from maintenance configurations, you typically need permissions for Maintenance Configurations and Virtual Machines
You can create custom role as below-
Goto subscription-> IAM-> +Add dropdown-> add custom role

Create your custom role, fill in the standard stuffs like role name description, etc and under permissions add these-




You can choose any additional permissions as per your requirement.
next under scope it should auto populate with your subscription ID-

save it-

Now go to the user / admin who will handle all this maintenance activity and assign him/her this custom role from add role section, filter out with the custom role name you gave and assign


This is the json for the custom rule, you will get your own while creating-
{
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "Maintenance Config VM Updater",
        "description": "Role with permissions to update maintenance configurations and associate VMs with them",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/subscriptions/20df4f6c-0ab2-4a88-82d5-9d23dbddfc7d"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Maintenance/maintenanceConfigurations/write",
                    "Microsoft.Maintenance/maintenanceConfigurations/read",
                    "Microsoft.Maintenance/configurationAssignments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Maintenance/configurationAssignments/read",
                    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read",
                    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write"
                ],
                "notActions": [],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}

You can also create this from powershell, checkout step 9 of this MS document

